# How to using imported style from index.js in imported html file in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Lets say I have `index.js` file, this is a main app file which import style file from directory, and import html template for specific part from other directory like this:

`index.js`:

```
import mRayStyle from './styles/Mray.module.css';
import mRayTemplate from './controllers/MrayTemplate.html';
```

`Mray.module.css`:

```
.mainBGColor {
  background-color: #25605f;
}

.mainFontColor {
  color: #25605f;
}

.mainSection {
  width: 62.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`MrayTemplate.html`:

```
<div class="mainBGColor">
  <div class="mainWrapper">
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, What I need is using imported style from Mray.module.css inside MrayTemplate.html, I try to use  `html-loader?interpolate` but `${mRayStyle.mainWrapper}` return error mRayStyle not defined

Additional Note:

> ```
> "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
> "itk": "^10.2.1",
> "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
> "style-loader": "^1.1.1",
> "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
> "vtk.js": "^13.2.1",
> "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
> "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
> "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
> "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
> "curry": "^1.2.0",
> "kw-web-suite": "^9.0.0",
> "webpack": "^4.41.4",
> "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1",
> "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
> ```

Webpack module rules:

```
module: {
rules: [
    { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader?interpolate' },
    { test: /\.stl/, loader: 'file-loader' },
    { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=81920' },
    { test: /\.svg$/, use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }] },
].concat(vtkRules, cssRules),},
```

Comment: Because it's not how style-loader works - it only adds whole style as usuall <style> when the specified module (where you imported the css) is called. You need another loader to do things like ${mRayStyle.mainWrapper}. Consider using txt loader for CSS - it let's you use some package to parse CSS and then you can just use it like: element.style[parsedProperty] = [parsedValue] I'm not familiar with all CSS loaders so maybe there is another doing all you need. The same when it comes to HTML...

Comment: @Zydnar thank you for comment, thats true, so that I try to find way thats resolve issue without using text loader or something else like including template and fetch class and replacement it with imported class...if we can make rule, setup config or have style loader fix it, will be perfect...

Answer (score 0):

You must use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/). This plugin automatically add css, js ,... assets to your html output.

Comment: I used it by default....but its not work...and this is my config ```new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        favicon: './src/logo.png',
        template: './src/htmlTemplate.html',
    }),```

Comment: your template must be like [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/#basic-usage)